# Extract values from a list of dictionaries in Ansible

Tags: list, loops, dictionary, ansible, jinja2

I have this playbook and I need to find a way to display the values of the list of dictionaries under `prerequisite` knowing that we have different key names. how can I display theses values keeping the same syntax of my playbook?

Expected output:

```
"linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
"mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64"
"linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
"mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64"
"linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
"mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64"
"linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
"mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64"
```

---

```yaml
- name: "extract values from a list of dictionaries"
 hosts: localhost
 tasks:
 - name: "adding variables"
   set_fact:
     products:
       mysql_8_0_19:
         CentOS_7:
           signature: "mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64"
           url: "linux/mysql/8.0.19/mysql-community-server-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
         pymysql_url: "linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/PyMySQL-0.9.3.tar.gz"
         prerequisite:
         - mysql_c_common_url: "linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
           mysql_c_common_signature: "mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64"
         - mysql_c_libs_url: "linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
           mysql_c_libs_signature: "mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64"
         - mysql_c_client_url: "linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
           mysql_c_client_signature: "mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64"
         - mysql_shell_url: "linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm"
           mysql_shell_signature: "mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64"

 - name: " display "
   debug:
     msg: "{{ item }}"
   with_items: "{{ products.mysql_8_0_19.prerequisite }}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the values of a dictionary in Ansible with an *"unknown"* set of keys usually call for the usage of [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#transforming-dictionaries-into-lists).

Your use case does fit the bill, you just have to [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) this filter on all elements of the `prerequisite` list, then [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) it and finally extract the values with another `map` filter.

So, you can achieve what you need with the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: >-
    {{ 
      products.mysql_8_0_19.prerequisite 
      | map('dict2items') 
      | flatten 
      | map(attribute='value') 
    }}
```

*<sup>You might want to add a `| list` filter at the end if you are on an old version of Ansible and get an error like `<generator object do_map at 0x7f3xxxxx>`</sup>*

---

Given the task:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      products.mysql_8_0_19.prerequisite
      | map('dict2items')
      | flatten
      | map(attribute='value')
  vars:
    products:
      mysql_8_0_19:
        prerequisite: "{{ prerequisite }}"
    prerequisite:
      - mysql_c_common_url: >-
          linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis{#- allows line wrap -#}
          /mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
        mysql_c_common_signature: >-
          mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
      - mysql_c_libs_url: >-
          linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis{#- allows line wrap -#}
          /mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
        mysql_c_libs_signature: >-
          mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
      - mysql_c_client_url: >-
          linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis{#- allows line wrap -#}
          /mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
        mysql_c_client_signature: >-
          mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
      - mysql_shell_url: >-
          linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis{#- allows line wrap -#}
          /mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
        mysql_shell_signature: >-
          mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
```

This yields:

```yaml
- linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
- mysql-community-common-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
- linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
- mysql-community-libs-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
- linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
- mysql-community-client-8.0.11-1.el7.x86_64
- linux/mysql/8.0.19/prerequis/mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
- mysql-shell-8.0.19-1.el7.x86_64
```